# Javascript return in Function

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function fromTo(x,y){
    return function(){
     if(x < y ){
      return x++;
     }
}

function element(arr,fun){
    return function(){
         //this is wrong 
     return arr[fun()];

        //this is correct
        var yy = fun();
        return arr[yy];
    }
}

//Testing of javascript below;

var e = element(['a','b','c','d'],fromTo(1,3));
e();
e();
e();
```

why can't i return arr[fun()];

instead, i have to declare a variable and store the value of the function like..

var yy = fun(); and then return arr[yy];

Comment: What's the error? Why can't you write it the first way?

Comment: Count the braces in your first function. This doesn't appear to have anything to do with the commented lines.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close function definition for the returned function from `fromTo`.

```js
function fromTo(x,y){
    return function(){
     if(x < y ){
      return x++;
     }
    }
}

function element(arr,fun){
    return function(){
     return arr[fun()];
    }
}
```